# Find all $n$ for which $19 \mid 10^n - 1$

Tags: divisibility

For what values of $n$ (positive integer) does 19 divide $10^n-1$ evenly?  The question arises in my fooling around with $2$-parasitic numbers.  And I know this is true for $n = 18, 36, 54$ (by computing!)  I expect this to be so for all multiples of $18.$
Would appreciate any feedback.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed.

A proof relies on *lil' Fermat*: we know that $\varphi(19)=18$, hence  for all $N$ coprime to $19$, we have $N^18\equiv 1$\mod 19. This is true for $10$, which means its order modulo $19$ is a  divisor of $18$, i.e. one of $2,3,6, 9$ or $18$. It is straightforward to check recursively it is $18$.

Comment: Well, that was easy!  Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

That is correct.  Once you know that $19\mid 10^{18}-1$ you can note that $10^{18k}-1=(10^{18}-1)(1+10^{18}+10^{36}+\cdots+ 10^{18(k-1)})$

Comment: Thanks fo that.  However, the real question is are those the only values, and how do you prove it?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question as to whether $10^k \equiv_1 19$ *only* for $k$ that is a multiple of 18: You can easily check the following: $10^{18+\ell} \equiv_{19} 10^{\ell}$ for each nonegative integer $\ell$. 
Indeed,

$$10^{18+\ell} \mod 19 = ((10^{18} \mod 19)\times(10^{\ell} \mod 19) \mod 19)$$

$$=1 \times (10^{\ell} \mod 19)$$

So calculate $10^{\ell} \mod 19$ for each $\ell=2,3,4,5,6,\ldots, 17$. This can be done via brute force without too much trouble.